# Hadoop Edge HDFS points to local FS

Tags: hadoop, gateway

I have done my Hadoop cluster including 1 NameNode and 2 DataNodes and everything works perfectly :)
Now, I want to add a Hadoop Edge (aka Hadoop Gateway), I followed instructions [here](https://dwbi.org/etl/bigdata/187-set-up-client-node-gateway-node-in-hadoop-cluster) and finally, I execute :

> hadoop fs -ls /

But unfortunately, I expected to see my HDFS's content but I see my local FS :

```
Found 22 items
-rw-r--r--   1 root root          0 2017-03-30 16:44 /autorelabel
dr-xr-xr-x   - root root      20480 2017-03-30 16:49 /bin
...
drwxr-xr-x   - root root      20480 2016-07-08 17:31 /home
```

I think my core-site.xml is configurated as needed with specific property :

```
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://hadoopnodemaster1:8020/</value>
</property>
```

hadoopmaster1 is my **namenode** and is reachable ..

I don't understand why I see my Local FS and not my HDFS .. Thank you :)

Comment: The edge node's `core-site.xml` should contain the same configurations as the cluster. Looks like it is not yet configured.

Comment: This is the same configuration .. I copied it by scp :(

Comment: Can you verify by running this command `hdfs getconf -confKey fs.default.name`

Comment: For sure : 
17/03/30 20:47:00 INFO Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated. Instead, use fs.defaultFS
hdfs://hadoopmaster1:8020/

Comment: This command was executed in edge node? And what result do you get on executing `hdfs dfs -ls /` in the namenode!